# JAVASCRIPT: Redirecting to Homepage after successful Ajax response on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect, authentication

I am trying to redirect to Homepage from SignIn Page after the validation of user credentials is done. The response is working perfectly fine. 
On getting a successful response, I want to redirect to Homepage.
I am using Javascript for client side and PHP on server side.

I have tried all the possible solutions provided elsewhere on this site.

Here is the script for redirection on SignIn page:

> $(document).ready(function(){
>       $("#SignInForm").submit(function(){
>
> ```
>   var em = document.getElementById("Email").value;
>     var ps = document.getElementById("Password").value;       var obj;        $.ajax({
>           url: 'WebService/SignIn.php',
>           type: 'post',
>           async: false,
>           data:       {
>     Email: em,
>       Password: ps
>   },
>           dataType: 'json',
>           success: function(data)         {       var str = JSON.stringify(data);          obj = JSON.parse(str);
>
>
>     if(obj.status == 1)       {
>                   window.location="Homepage.html";
>               }       else        {           alert("Invalid Username/Password")          }
>           },
>           error: function(xhr){       //alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );         alert("An error occured. Please Try Again");        }
>
>           })
>
>
>
>
>
> }); }); </script>
> ```

A simple

> window.location="Homepage.html";

should be suffice. But it isn't working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.submit` will already **refresh the page** unless you prevent its default behavior. Besides, if you need to redirect, why don't you do that on the server side without using an ajax request? In a nutshell, whatever you currently are going to do, if you don't **prevent** the default action of the submit button it will **never** work, because before you even send the request to the server you will already have started the reload process.

Comment: @briosheje I need to validate the user credentials before redirecting. Hence, using ajax. Please tell me how do I prevent the default behavior of .submit?

Comment: replace `.submit(function()` with: `.submit(function(e)` (<-- note the `e`). Right after that, add: `e.preventDefault();`. In this way, whenever you click the submit button, it WON'T execute its default behavior, but will do absolutely nothing, allowing you to perform an ajax request. Example without the `.preventDefault();`: http://jsfiddle.net/hhjqqeza/ . Example WITH the preventedafult: http://jsfiddle.net/hhjqqeza/1/ . See the difference? in the first case, you get redirected automatically, in the second case, you don't, so you can do your ajax request and redirect manually.

Comment: @briosheje: Thank you soo much. Its working perfectly fine. Post this as a answer so that anyone with same issue in future can be helped.

Comment: Great, keep in mind (just for the sake of telling you) that for such kind of requests ajax is not needed, a simple form is just enough to handle a login form, I would rather recommend you to use AJAX in other circumstances (where effectively needed ;D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the submit action:

By default, in fact, the submit action redirects to the url provided in the **action** (form parameter): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Hence, in order to be able to perform an AJAX request, you have to first **prevent** the default action performed by the submit.

Just replace:

```
$("#SignInForm").submit(function(){

  var em = document.getElementById("Email").value;
```

With:

```
$("#SignInForm").submit(function(e){ // <-- note the e
  e.preventDefault();
  var em = document.getElementById("Email").value;
```

Live example of what happens WITHOUT preventing the default action:

http://jsfiddle.net/hhjqqeza/

Live example of what happens by PREVENTING the default action:

http://jsfiddle.net/hhjqqeza/1/

Answer (score 3):

`window.location.href = "homepage.html"` ?

Comment: Nope not working. As reported by @briosheje, I suspect it's got to do something with .submit